# How to install Qiskit with only Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, qiskit

I want to use Jupyter Notebook without installing Anaconda on Ubuntu 18.04. I do not want to use any virtual environment. What can I do to install Qiskit?

I have tried to install Qiskit with pip3.

```
pip3 install qiskit
```

This shows the following message

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

But if I try to import qiskit from terminal with this shows no error. But when I try to import qiskit from Jupyter Notebook it says that

> there is not module named qiskit

Any suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you check if jupyter and terminal are pointing to same python installation ?

Comment: Actually, I started python from the terminal with python3 command. And opened a new Python3 notebook from Jupyter. I don't know how to check it. Please suggest how can I check if they are pointing to same python installation.

Comment: `import sys; sys.executable` from both python console and jupyter notebook.

Comment: Okay. I have found a problem here. They are not generating the same result. In the terminal it shows ''/home/protik/anaconda3/bin/python3" and in Jupyter Notebook it shows "'/home/protik/anaconda3/bin/python". How can I fix this now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have different python installations. Install qiskit in the python installation pointed by jupyter. Use below from jupyter notebook

```
!pip3 install qiskit
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. In the meantime, I tried this line in google colaboratory to install Qiskit and work.